# Canvas inside tkinter dont draw line

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to draw line when my left mouse button is pressed

It worked when i did it on another file outside of the "Window" class but now it doesnt

the prints tell me the methods are still working

I am beginner please provide example =)

```
import tkinter as tk
size = [960,800]
    
line_id = None
line_points = []
line_options = {}

class Window(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Calcul mental")
        self.master.minsize(size[0],size[1])
        self.grid(sticky=tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)
        
        top=self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        global  line_id, line_points, line_options
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas()
        
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.set_start)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw_line)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.end_line)
        self.bind('<Button-3>', self.clear_line)
        

    def draw_line(self,event):
        global line_id,line_points,line_options
        print("draw")
        line_points.extend((event.x, event.y))
        line_id = self.canvas.create_line(line_points, **line_options,tags="draw")
        
    def set_start(self,event):
        global line_points
        print("start")
        line_points.extend((event.x, event.y))
        
    def end_line(self,event=None):
        global line_id
        print('end')
        line_points.clear()
        line_id = None
        
    def clear_line(self,event):
        print("clear line")
        self.canvas.delete("draw")

Window().mainloop()
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: You forgot to call layout function (`.pack()` or `.grid()`) on `self.canvas`, so it is hidden.  Also you need to bind events on `self.canvas` instead. And `Window` should inherits from `tk.Tk` instead.

Comment: you forgot to `pack` or `grid` the canvas, don't you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this line line 30.

```
self.canvas.grid()
```