# Canvas doesnt draw line correctly because of method problem

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

The methods "start" and "clear line" only work when my mouse cursor is on the tkinter window not the canvas

But the point is to draw line on the canvas. How it is this way?

Tried to put as method argument (self.canvas) instead of (self) but it did not work and there is not much left to change on the method so i dont know

I am beginner please provide example

```
import tkinter as tk

size = [960,800]

line_id = None
line_points = []
line_options = {}

class Window(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Calcul mental")
        self.master.minsize(size[0],size[1])
        self.grid(sticky=tk.E+tk.W+tk.N+tk.S)
        
        top=self.winfo_toplevel()
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        global  line_id, line_points, line_options
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas( self,border=5,bg = "white", width=size[0], height=size[1]/2 )
        self.canvas.grid()
        
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.set_start)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw_line)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.end_line)
        self.bind('<Button-3>', self.clear_line)
        
    def draw_line(self,event):
        global line_id,line_points,line_options
        print("draw")
        line_points.extend((event.x, event.y))
        line_id = self.canvas.create_line(line_points, **line_options,tags="draw")

    def set_start(self,event):
        global line_points
        print("start")
        line_points.extend((event.x, event.y))

    def end_line(self,event=None):
        global line_id
        print('end')
        line_points.clear()
        line_id = None

    def clear_line(self,event):
        print("clear line")
        self.canvas.delete("draw")

Window().mainloop()
```

Comment: Try moving the bindings to the canvas instead of the frame.

Comment: I have already mentioned that you need to bind on the canvas in my comment in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76295936/canvas-inside-tkinter-dont-draw-line).

Comment: @acw1668 yes i see it now i dont know why i did not really understood what you meant last time sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help @Bryan Oakley and @acw1668 =)

i changed

```
self.bind('<Button-1>', self.set_start)
self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw_line)
self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.end_line)
self.bind('<Button-3>', self.clear_line)
```

to

```
self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.set_start)
self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw_line)
self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.end_line)
self.canvas.bind('<Button-3>', self.clear_line)
```

and it works